# IntelliJ - debug mode - search text in program memory

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea

I'm working with undocumented 3rd party library. I know that there is a certain *String* stored somewhere in one of the fields deep in the library (dynamic value that I can predict, but I want to get it from the API of the library).

Is there a way to search (something like fulltext search?) through the **full** program memory while in the debug mode and while stopped on certain breakpoint? I want to find which field in which object actually stores this value.

(I know I could do manual dump and grep, I'm more interested if IntelliJ supports this feature)

Comment: No, there is no such feature in IntelliJ IDEA.

Answer (score 0):

IntelliJ 2015 and 2016 can [decompile Java classes](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/#built-in-tools), so you can get the string from the library <s>without debugging at all</s>. Use Navigate -> Declaration or Navigate -> Implementation(s) to see a decompiled version of the byte code for the class. The decompiler can get everything except the original variable names and comments from a library.

Comment: This String is dynamic, it should be known when I'm waiting on the breakpoint

Comment: Debugging can use use the decompiler as well to find the code with the variable. You may need to walk up the stack to find which method has the string.